# Is it all right to inflect magazine and newspaper names?

Tags: article, declension, inflection, proper-noun

If I am reading the magazine "der Spiegel", should I say

> (a) Ich lese jetzt der Spiegel.

or

> (b) Ich lese jetzt den Spiegel.

?

It sounds weird to me to inflect a part of a proper name as in (b).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do decline names. This will also include an article even if this is part of the name. Sometimes the article will even be omitted when building a contraction with a preposition.

#### Examples:

> - **Der Spiegel:** In Artikeln des Spiegel**s** wird Hintergrundwissen vermittelt.
> - **Die Zeit:** In der Zeit lese ich regelmäßig das Dossier.
> - **Süddeutsche Zeitung:** Journalisten der Süddeutsche**n** Zeitung sind gut informiert.
> - **Das Erste:** Im Ersten kommt die Tagesschau.

Only rarely the article became an integral part of a name. It is then not separated with a blank. In this case it will not be inflected:

> - Im **DASDING** spielt ein Jugendprogramm.

In case we still want or need to include an non-inflected article of a name or a title [we should put them in quotes](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Anfuehrungszeichen.html):

> - Bei "Wiki und die starken Männer" spielen Wikinger ein große Rolle.
> - Ich möchte gerne ein Abonnement der "Die Zeit" bestellen.
> - Ich verpasse kein Konzert von "Die Ärzte".
> - Im "Das Erste" kommt die Tagesschau.

Comment: Puh. Hast du einen Verweis zu einer vertrauenswürdigen Seite, wo das im letzten Abschnitt Gesagte bestätigt wird? Den 1. und 3. Satz akzeptiere ich, aber beim 2. und 4. würde ich jedem, der das ernsthaft sagt, eins auf den Deckel geben. Imho müsst Satz 3 - um 2 und 4 zu gleichen - wenn schon "Ich verpasse kein Konzert von den 'Die Ärtze'" lauten, womit ich den Satz aber ablehne. Der 2. Satz ist imho OK, wenn man sagt: "Ich möchte gern ein Abonnement von 'Die Zeit' bestellen" - Ob ich es schön finde, steht dann aber noch mal auf nem anderen Blatt.

Comment: Das waren aber die starken Männer, nicht die wilden, oder? Das Problem mit Anführungsstrichen ist, dass man sie so schlecht aussprechen kann. Was ist mit der Beilage der Zeit, heißt die die "die Zeitbeilage"? Es gibt einen Markenfetischismus der Werbewirtschaft die die Namen (aus durchsichtigen Gründen) wie unberührbar behandelt und deswegen auch solche Ungeheuerlichkeiten produziert wie "Kaiser's Supermarkt" - zu deren Erfüllungsgehilfe muss man sich aber nicht machen.

Comment: @Em1: wenn wir die Artikel **nicht** in Anführungszeichen setzen, **müssen** wir sie konjugieren. Also nur in Anführungszeichen geht unkonjugiert überhaupt. Ob das nun gut ist, sei mal dahingestellt, ich würde das jedenfalls nicht machen.

Comment: Sorry, war nicht klar in meiner Aussage. Mir gehts nicht um die Anführungszeichen. Das ist selbstverständlich richtig. Mir geht's um die zwei aufeinanderfolgenden Artikel "der 'die Zeit'" oder "In dem 'Das Erste'" oder wie dann korrekterweise (*hust*) im dritten Satz "von den *Die Ärzte'". In dem Link, den du hinzugefügt hast, wird es so **keinmal** angeführt. Da heißt es wenn "des 'Spiegels'" aber nicht "des 'der Spiegel'". Oder da heisst es "der 'Kleinen Nachtmusik'" und nicht "der 'Eine kleine Nachtmusik'". Genau genommen, hat der Link meine Meinung bestätigt, dass Satz 2 und 4 falsch sind.

Comment: Em1 hat recht nach 4.4 in http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf59-62.html , aber 2. und 4. sind trotzdem richtig, weil sie ohne Leerzeichen sind bzw. in Anführungsstricheln stehen. Dann macht man das freilich so.

Answer (score 0):

- Ich abonnierte nicht den Spiegel
- Er las in der Zeit
- Ein Artikel des Sterns

Die Produkte heißen Spiegel, Zeit und Stern, nicht Der Spiegel, Die Zeit und Der Stern.

Comment: Seh ich nicht so. Die Zeit schreibt sich ja selbst sogar eigentlich "DIE ZEIT". Gehöre der Artikel nicht dazu, wäre es "Die ZEIT" (siehe z.B. [Impressum](http://www.zeit.de/impressum/impressum-print)). Dennoch stimmt es, dass in einem Fließtext der Artikel getrennt gesehen wird und folglich dekliniert wird. (But yes, the web presentation is called "Zeit Online" again) - Selbiges gilt für den "DER SPIEGEL", nicht aber für den "stern".

Comment: Und die Beatles hießen auch nicht Beatles, sondern die Die Beatles, weil sie Die Beatles draufgeschrieben haben, mit Artikel? Heißt es auch der Der-Spiegelredakteur? Das ist doch albern!

Comment: Nur weil's albern ist, muss es nicht unwahr sein. Gerade bei "Der Spiegel" oder "Die Ärzte" ist für mich der Eigenname recht deutlich.

Comment: Genau. Die Beatles sind "The Beatles". Und @npst, genau genommen sogar mit kleinem a und mit 3 Punkten druff. ;) Aber das würde man wiederum im Fließtext nie so schreiben.

Comment: @npst: "die Ärzte" ist ein super Beispiel, denn da hab' ich beides gleich oft gehört: "Ich war bei die Ärzte." / "Ich war bei den Ärzten"...