# Is omitting »The« from the newspaper name »The Times« grammatically correct?

Tags: article

There is a British national newspaper called *The Times*. *The* is part of the name of the newspaper, as can be seen on the [website](http://www.thetimes.co.uk/) of the newspaper as well as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times).

The following two paragraphs appear in the *Frankfurter Allgemeine* article "[Britisches Finanzministerium warnt vor hartem Brexit](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/wirtschaftspolitik/britisches-finanzministerium-warnt-vor-hartem-brexit-14476404.html)". In the first paragraph, the British newspaper is referred to as *The Times*. In the second paragraph, however, it's already referred to as *die „Times“*. Is the name of the newspaper correctly used in the second paragraph?

> Das britische Finanzministerium hat vor erheblichen Kosten gewarnt, sollte Großbritannien infolge des Brexit-Votums aus dem Europäischen Binnenmarkt ausscheiden. Das geht aus einem internen Papier hervor, das der britischen Tageszeitung **„The Times“** vorliegt.
>
> Das Finanzministerium wolle mit dem Papier Kabinettsmitglieder von dem
>   potenziellen Schaden überzeugen, den ein „harter Brexit“ mit sich
>   bringe, berichtet **die „Times“** am Dienstag. Die Zahlen basierten auf
>   einem Bericht, der bereits vor dem Brexit-Votum veröffentlicht wurde
>   und damals von Befürwortern eines EU-Austritts als „Panikmache“
>   abgetan wurde.

Comment: I suspect this is related: [*Is it all right to inflect magazine and newspaper names?*](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8281/is-it-all-right-to-inflect-magazine-and-newspaper-names) The English article in *The Times* is not German enough to be inflected, but still too comprehensible to German readers to be ignored as an article (so combining it with an additional inflected German article would look weird, like two articles). Possibly, this is why the resulting compromise is to drop the English article and just use the inflected German one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is correct usage.

The *the* in The Times’ name — while being part of the name — is an article. As such, it can be replaced with a German article if German grammar requires one. This is usually done only for articles which the general German public would (more or less) recognise as articles — typically this means English and French articles are okay, other languages’ articles probably not. Compare:

> Die französische Tageszeitung ***Le Monde*** berichtet von einer ungewöhnlichen Demonstration in Paris. Laut **der *Monde*** marschierten 50 Bürgersteigkritiker eine kleine Seitenstraße auf und ab.
>
> Die spanische Tageszeitung ***El País*** berichtet von einer ähnlichen Veranstaltung in Madrid. Laut ***El País*/der *País*** waren es dort aber nur 15 Leute.
>
> Die israelische Zeitung ***Ha’Aretz*** kennt auch ein ähnliches Beispiel aus Tel Aviv. Dort demonstrierten laut **(der) *Ha’Aretz*** 25 Leute – allerdings handelte es sich dort um Randsteinkritiker.

It would be pretty common for *Le Monde* to lose its article in favour of a German one (note that a *Zeitung* is feminine, even if its name is masculine). For *El País,* I can imagine it happening, but it is also very likely for the article to just remain there. Nobody recognises the Hebrew article *Ha,* thus the Israeli newspaper’s name is never modified.